# What does $settings['setting'] = "setting" Do?

Tags: php, mybb

I am using a bulletin board called [mybb](http://www.mybb.com) and came across the following code:-

```
$settings['setting'] = "setting"
```

What does it do,  google has failed me, because I don't know what to search for exactly.

How would I make use of it?

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php Don't read documentation @ ask on stackoverflow

Comment: In which situation are you setting this? $_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER, $_HTTP, $_FILE, $_SESSION? Are those what you're talking about?

Comment: That depends on your script. It's impossible to say without any more code or information.

Comment: You need to add more context. Without anything specific (e.g. the software this is relating to) it only means that an array variable is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement sets the value of the item in the array `$settings` identified by key `setting` to the string `"setting"`.

You would use it like this:-

```
$settings['setting'] = "setting";
```

And if, for example, you wanted to echo the value you would do so like this :-

```
echo $settings['settings'];
```

Comment: The reason @Claudix answered like this was because all you showed us was one line of code that did exactly as he says. When you say "setting" do you mean things like _GET, _POST, _SERVER, _HTTP, _FILE, _SESSION, etc...?

Comment: In codes MyBB there is a whole file with just $settings['setting'] = “setting”; and i was wondering what it does, and how you use it.

Comment: @ChocCookieRaider That would be configuration for MyBB. You can find a lot about that by reading their documentation: http://docs.mybb.com/.

Comment: That says nothing about it, and I'm mainly wondering how would i use it in my own scripts?

Comment: I edited in an example of its use :)

Comment: Thanks! That will be a great help!

Comment: You need to flesh out your question a bit, it doesn't show much effort does it?

Comment: I couldnt find anything about it, Google didnt come up with anything about it because i didn't know exactly what to seach, and i didn't know what it was called, so i couldnt search for it on the php.net site.

Comment: But you could have explained where it was from at least to give the question some context. The more effort you put into your question the better the answers you will get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use different names so that you might see that the keyword 'setting' is in all 3 cases of your code, arbitrary:

```
$animals = array("cat"=>"mamal","ant"=>"insect");
$animals['cat']="insect";
```

the first line merely declares two key value pairs within an array called $animals
the second line merely sets the value of key 'cat' to "insect".

```
echo $animals['ant'];
```

this last code line should print "insect".